# How to populate installer variables from customized actions to the installation context?

Tags: java, install4j

I would like to populate programmatically-created installation variables in customized actions to the installation context, in order to use these in the IDE like `${installer:myVar}` for example.

When I create the variable and set it to the context with `getContext().setVariable("myVar", "123")`, theses variable do not appear in the *Bound Variables* tab of the *Select Installation Variable* dialog as the others do that are set using the *Set Variable* action.

Is there a way to populate my custom variable so it's visible here?

Answer (score 0):

If you pre-define installer variables, they show up in the "Select installer runtime variable" dialog.

On the Screens & Actions step, select the installer then activate the "Installer variables" tab and click the "Configure Predefined Installer Variables" button. You don't actually have to specify a value when you pre-define a variable.

If you develop a custom action with the API, you can use the `Install4JPropertyDescriptor.CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME` context when registering the property containing the variable name in the `BeanInfo` class:

```
addPropertyDescriptor(Install4JPropertyDescriptor.create("propertyName", 
    getBeanClass(), "Variable property", "Description", 
    Install4JPropertyDescriptor.CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME));
```

Comment: When I provide an action with a field to set the name of the variable (mostly plain text fields) could I use the pre-configured variables then? And what about to share the customized action: the user has to know that he must configure such a predefined variable instead only set a name into the configuration text field. Is it right?

Comment: Okay, that's nearly the solution I expected. There is only one thing left. Now I found the variable in the "Bound variable" tab but when I select any bounded variable for my customized field it missing the installer prefix like `${installer:myVar}`. The value is only set to `myVar`. Where I have to configure this?

Comment: That cannot be done, the property is marked to hold a variable name, you would have to replace the variable yourself via `context.getVariable(variableName)`in your code.